# Run Azure Logic app on different subscription

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have logic app and Storage account both on different subscription. I want to run logic app when resource event occurs on storage account which is at different subscription. How I can do that..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to achieve this. Easiest one is to create a logic app for the storage account trigger in the same subscription and make it do an HTTP POST to the logic app created in different subscription. Let me know if you need detailed explanation on this.